# An internal error occurred during: "JPA Facet File Change Event Handler"

Tags: java, persistence, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I am new to JPA 2.0. I am using eclipse juno to create a JPA project(eclipseLink 2.0.2).

When creating the JPA Project i am getting an error as

> An internal error occurred during: "JPA Facet File Change Event
>   Handler".

On checking the log i get this:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/AbstractJPQLQueryHelper  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:607)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.internal.context.persistence.EclipseLink2_0PersistenceXmlContextNodeFactory.buildPersistenceUnit(EclipseLink2_0PersistenceXmlContextNodeFactory.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.persistence.GenericPersistence.buildPersistenceUnit(GenericPersistence.java:179)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.persistence.GenericPersistence.initializePersistenceUnits(GenericPersistence.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.persistence.GenericPersistence.(GenericPersistence.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.context.persistence.AbstractPersistenceXmlContextNodeFactory.buildPersistence(AbstractPersistenceXmlContextNodeFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.persistence.GenericPersistenceXml.buildPersistence(GenericPersistenceXml.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.persistence.GenericPersistenceXml.(GenericPersistenceXml.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaFactory.buildPersistenceXml(AbstractJpaFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.GenericRootContextNode.buildPersistenceXml(GenericRootContextNode.java:157)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.GenericRootContextNode.buildPersistenceXml(GenericRootContextNode.java:95)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.jpa1.context.GenericRootContextNode.(GenericRootContextNode.java:62)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaFactory.buildRootContextNode(AbstractJpaFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.buildRootContextNode(AbstractJpaProject.java:276)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.(AbstractJpaProject.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.internal.EclipseLinkJpaProjectImpl.(EclipseLinkJpaProjectImpl.java:26)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.internal.EclipseLinkJpaFactory.buildJpaProject(EclipseLinkJpaFactory.java:62)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.internal.EclipseLink2_0JpaFactory.buildJpaProject(EclipseLink2_0JpaFactory.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.internal.EclipseLink2_0JpaFactory.buildJpaProject(EclipseLink2_0JpaFactory.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildJpaProject(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:616)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildJpaProject(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.buildJpaProject(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:601)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.addJpaProject(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.checkForJpaFacetTransition_(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager$FacetFileChangeEventHandlerCommand.execute(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:750)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.utility.command.CommandJobCommandAdapter.execute(CommandJobCommandAdapter.java:39)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.utility.command.JobCommandJob.run(JobCommandJob.java:42)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.AbstractJPQLQueryHelper  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 43 more

I cannot find what this error and log refer to. Any help would be great as i am struggling at this point.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631371/why-is-eclipse-juno-4-2-running-jpa-java-change-event-handler-processes

Thought it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

Based on this bug report on Eclipse - [NoClassDefFoundError with JPA projects](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380254)
I had to uninstall the Hibernate Tools plugin to fix the error.

Looks like the base Eclipse doesn't have an issue, but if you have installed JBoss Tools plugins, they provide a non-compatible version of JPA classes, and that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I m also facing the same issue

Error is :

> An internal error occurred during: "JPA Facet File Change Event
>   Handler"

To Solve :

We need to uninstall the hibernate tools.
Our Eclipse doesn't have any problem but tool which we installed dynamically it have issue so better is to remove that tools.