# Eclipse JPA Project Change Event Handler (waiting)

Tags: eclipse

Why am I getting  'JPA Project Change Event Handler (waiting)', whenever I try to build my project.

I have some JPA projects in my workspace and It takes lot of time to build my project. It also leads to GC over limit with 6GB of heap space allocated to eclipse

I'm currently using Kepler. This issue did not occur in Helios.

There are some BugZilla entries for the above bug, but I can see them fixed. But not available in 4.3.1?

Any solutions/workarounds for the above issue?

Thanks

Comment: I am seeing this in Luna too.

Comment: It's happening to me in Mars 2 as well

Comment: On the same machine, hapening in Neon but not in Mars for me...

Comment: Happening in Neon.2, and not even using JPA.

Comment: Seeing this in eclipse photon

Comment: Its there in 2020-03 too

Comment: This problem is still happening with Eclipse 2022-06. While some of the solutions mentioned here work with a vanilla installation (both moving the features and plugins to another folder, or commenting out the entries in the bundles.info file), it seems it has become nearly impossible to install additional plugins without the jpa stuff enabled. For example, I cannot install Easy Console Grepper, Enhanced Class Decompiler, or the Darkest Dark theme from Genuitec.

Comment: I'm seeing it in Eclipse 2022-03 and the application is nearly unusable when it happens. This latest time, I tried to wait it out and after 20 minutes it's still stuck "Waiting" on the JPA event handler. I killed Eclipse from task manager, re-started, and it's still unresponsive. Finally after several more minutes, I'm able to right click on a project in project explorer and get any response at all, but it's still very slow. This has been a reoccurring issue.

Answer (score 176):

I had the same problem and I ended up finding out that this seems to be [a known bug in DALI](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386171)  (Eclipse Java Persistence Tools) since at least eclipse 3.8 which could cause the [save action in the java editor to be extremly slow](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361763).

Since this hasn't been fully resolved in Kepler (20130614-0229) yet and because I don't need JPT/DALI in my eclipse I ended up manually removing the `org.eclipse.jpt` features and plugins.

What I did was:

1.) exit eclipse

2.) go to my eclipse install directory

```
cd eclipse
```

and execute these steps:

*nix:

```
mkdir disabled
mkdir disabled/features disabled/plugins

mv plugins/org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled/plugins
mv features/org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled/features
```

windows:

```
mkdir disabled
mkdir disabled\features 
mkdir disabled\plugins

move plugins\org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled\plugins
for /D /R %D in (features\org.eclipse.jpt.*) do move %D disabled\features
```

3.) Restart eclipse.

*After startup and on first use eclipse may warn you that you need to **reconfigure your content-assist**. Do this in your preferences dialog.*

Done.

After uninstalling DALI/JPT my eclipse feels good again. No more blocked UI and waiting for seconds when saving a file.

Comment: On a side note: the eclipse team should probably try to open a discussion on the amount of included and not deselectable features/project included in a release. And it should maybe discuss ways to disable packaged features (such as JPT).

Comment: Same problem with 'JPA Project Change Event Handler' stalling Eclipse Luna Build 4.4.0. @mwhs solution works with Luna as well if you don't need the JPA tools (install JBoss Hibernate Tools instead, which are far more powerful anyway, if you're working with Hibernate)

Comment: Nice find! Unfortunately, the DALI bug is closed since 2012-08-29, but 2 years later I still had the same problems in Luna/STS 3.6.1 (with a Git repo outside of the workspace). I did not try your solution, as I also kept running into Remote System Explorer slowdowns (even though I tried to disable that), so in the end I just installed a vanilla Eclipse for Java (not even JEE), added JST Server Adapters &  extensions, m2e-wtp, and AspectJ Development Tools using  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update/. Lightning fast, finally.

Comment: Anyone know how to undo this?  Putting the plugins and features jars back didn't fix it...and I need my Dali tools back again (for a little while at least).

Comment: Either try restarting eclipse with `-clean` or if that doesn't do the job, then try using the "dropins" folder to reinstall the disabled plugins, instead of copying them directly back to the plugins and features directory.

Comment: Yes it worked, but removing the plugins caused FRAMEWORK EVENT ERROR and jboss tools in preferences disappeared. how can i fix this?

Comment: Had been having similar issues with slow downs and the status "Shared Project Change Event" under both Kepler and Luna. Luna I was using: eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64. To give an idea of size needed for this to become extremely annoying... I was seeing this when importing a work app spread out across just ~60 projects (all total, ~750 MB across ~30K files). It was effectively blocking me from doing anything in eclipse for 5-10 minutes. Tested this fix on Luna and my first impressions after making this change, is that it makes a HUGE difference (down to maybe 30sec + seems less intensive)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the command `move features\org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled\features` did not work for me (on Win7 x64) and I had to manage those manually. I suspect this is because this contains folders instead of files and... well, let's just say that after you've written enough windows batch scripts, you'll probably start to question if the language was in fact designed by an experimental Microsoft team composed entirely of illiterate drunken chimpanzees with severe ADHD. Or you may just wonder why OOTB Unix support wasn't added to the command prompt with the NTFS versions of Windows.

Comment: Hello, i'm using LUNA and I have the same problem. The second "move" command did not work for me, but I moved the files/folders manually, which is fine.
Besides that, now the Google App Engine integration with Maven projects is broken (in Servers, Runtime Environment i can't create an Google App Engine server) so I need to revert back enabling the plugins

Comment: All of you who are seeing the problem please add info to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386171 or even better a new bug with something reproducible. Then we can actually help investigate.

Comment: This actually caused me a lot of problems.  I have many multi-module maven projects and after this change, they were not consistently picking up on changes from each other.  I couldn't even do explicit maven updates (alt+f5) and cleans after builds on command-line and be assured a project further in the chain was going to resolve classes it needed.

Comment: @zpangwin I updated with a command that does work in windows 7

Comment: Well, its now 2016 and Eclipse Neon still has this problem.

Comment: I don't found those plugins/features on eclipse (Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)) folder, but I found in `~/.p2/pool`. Those steps worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me for STS Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE Build Id: 201602251025. Thumbs up for saving lots of time.

Comment: Amazingly enough, this problem still persists in eclipse oxygen (september 2017), and your solution did the trick for me.

Comment: still happen with eclipse 4.10.

Comment: The folder structure and contents are different for *Eclipse Oxygen (MacOS)* version. Folder `plugins` has ONLY ONE jar: `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar`. And, folder `features` does not exist.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014872/7678737) by *Anil Bharadia* worked for me.

Comment: 2023 and still happens for me. Maybe it is time to switch to other IDE.

Answer (score 78):

Don't know why, my Neon Eclipse still having this issue, it doesn't seem to be fixed in Mars version as many people said.

I found that using command is too troublesome, I delete the plugin away via the Eclipse Installation Manager.

### Neon: [Help > Installation Details > Installed Software]

### Oxygen: [Preferences > Install/Update > Installed Software]

Just select the plugin "Dali Java Persistence Tools -JPA Support" and click "uninstall" will do. Please take note my screen below doesn't have that because I already uninstalled.

[image]

Comment: I also removed "EclipseLink JPA Support" as well

Comment: This solution worked for me, for a period... then after months open again Eclipse and it still boring me with this... I uninstalled all DALI plugins (months ago), and in the beginning was working, but now looks like this have no effects anymore...

Answer (score 41):

I still have the same issue in Neon.2
My solution is to disable the JPA Configurator.

Open the Eclipse Preferences (not the project prefs!). Go to Maven --> Java EE Integration and disable the JPA Configurator. I also disabled the JAX-RS Configurator and the JSF Configurator.

From that point on the JPA Project Change Event Handler doesn't show up anymore.

Restart Eclipse if the change does not take effect immediately.

Comment: Great, thanks, I was still seeing this issue in Photon 4.8.0 on Mac and this is the only proposed solution that works for me.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Didnt work for me in Eclipse 2020

Answer (score 27):

I have disabled (unchecked) the JPA validator.

Now whenever I save the file, it shows only one task for JPA Project Change Event Handler and only 2 or 3 for JPA Java Change Event Handler.

And most important, the UI Hang issue is resolved.

Please refer following screen shot for the setting I have made :

[image]

Comment: Amazing - I have JPA Validation unchecked but I still get the JPA Change Event Handler!

Comment: This worked for me. In fact, it's better to DISABLE ALL, and enable ONLY what's required. For example, if you're not working with 'web projects' you don't need any sort of jsp*, jsf*, html, etc.

This has helped fine-tune validation for each module/project. Saving precious time - a lot.

Comment: Issue still exists in 2024 (Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0), Build id: 20231201-2043). This solution is the one working.

Answer (score 16):

There is another way to disable JPA tools for the project, that doesn't require to uninstall JPA features/plug-ins. I tested on https://github.com/Jasig/uPortal project wich was mentioned in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386171 and claims to have similar problems:

1. Switch to Eclipse Projects Explorer View to see the projects with JPA Facet Enabled (there should be "JPA Content" node);
2. Select the project of interest which has "JPA Content" node and select Properties from context menu or press Alt+Enter to show Properties dialog for the project;
3. Select "Project Facets" node in tree with categories;
4. Clear JPA check box in project facets list and press OK.

After disabling JPA facet for uportal-war project form repository above I don't see any JPA related jobs in Eclipse Progress View.

Comment: This might work for some but for most people it won't work. I removed the JPA facet from all my projects but I still get a hung up environment. The reason might be related to Maven restoring JPA or something like that but the fact is that this doesn't work even after following these very logical steps.

Comment: above solution worked for me in eclipse 2020-03. Thanks @dgolovin.

Answer (score 9):

Well this was initially asked 7 years ago....So let me give a very stable answer to it.

**I am using eclipse 2021-09 (yes..the one just released few days ago)**

**TO TURN OFF JPA Project Change Event Handler (waiting)**

1. Make sure no instance of eclise is running. Do suspend the validations for JPA from windows > preference > Validations
2. Go to **[Installation directory]\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator**
3. Edit **bundles.info** using notepad++ or wordpad or notepad in such a way that
4. You have to remove the lines that has org.[something].jpa (Sorry I don't remember exact name :P) and save the file.
5. Launch the eclipse and there you go, you won't see those troublesome **"JPA Project Change Event Handler (waiting)"** message in your elipse's console.

Comment: if we do the 1st step is it also important to delete lines from bundles.info? @Akshay

Comment: Yes, that will work as 2-step deletion to ensure complete removal

Comment: I'm using `Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)` and followed this step, looks like it's working!

Comment: Hello, where is  "windows > preference > Validations" ? is not in Eclispe? but "Make sure no instance of eclise is running." .... so where is this menu/setting ?

Answer (score 8):

minor correction to mwhs's answer for the ***windows*** portion...

The move command does not work for the .\features folder because... well, frankly because Windows is retarded (you can use wildcards with 'move' on files, but apparently wildcards + folders == ignore the command). Anyway, this should work as an alternative to the windows snippet provided for step #2 in his answer.

as a batch file:

```
@echo off
set eclipse_dir=C:\eclipse_luna

mkdir disabled
mkdir disabled\features 
mkdir disabled\plugins

move plugins\org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled\plugins
for /f %%i in ('dir "%eclipse_dir%\features\org.eclipse.jpt.*" /ad /b') do (
    move "%eclipse_dir%\features\%%i" "%eclipse_dir%\disabled\features\%%i"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you cannot find your eclipse dir. Because, I had such problem on mac we can remember that eclipse is using OSGi, so we can go to Target Platform and disable features/plugins that were described above: org.eclipse.jpt.*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution for eclipse photon seems to be:

1. open ./eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
2. delete the lines starting with org.eclipse.jpt (might work to only remove org.eclipse.jpt.jpa)

Answer (score -2):

The issue seems to be resolved with the new Eclipse. The plugin isn't available with Java Enterprise suite.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this problem with Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0).

Answer (score -5):

It works for me. Eclipse 2021-09. You have to delete all lines  containing jpa.