# Eclipse Kepler - Projet Shared Event Updates

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to know what is the message "Projet Shared Event Updates" in Eclipse Kepler ?

Thx.

Comment: How about giving us a hint as to the context this is appearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the benefit of anyone else who stumbles onto this from google, please see mwhs's answer here which worked great for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20142580/1218290

edit:
I just realized the OP didn't mention wanting to get rid of it, just that he wanted to know what it was. I had stumbled on this while trying to find out what the heck this status was as well, but more because it was slowing down my eclipse considerably (i.e. I was looking for a way to shut it off). The linked answer gives some good background info even if you just want to know more about it but I am referring this more on the basis of "how do i get rid of this junk". ;-)