# How to cancel task "Updating Navigator Content Viewer" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse is ver slow because the task "Updating Navigator Content Viewer" is always running. i didn't find any option to disable this.

Do you know how i can remove this task?

Answer (score 3):

Turn off Project -> Build Automatically and **immediately** restart Eclipse for a temporary solution...

See also here: [Eclipse Kepler JPA Project Change Event Handler (waiting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649847/eclipse-kepler-jpa-project-change-event-handler-waiting)

and here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2201275

It seems like any of the following may possibly help:

- Uninstalling the Dali Java Persistence Tools plugins (Help -> Installation Details -> Installed Software)
- Going to Window -> Preferences -> Oracle -> AppXray, and checking Disable AppXray
- Putting -Doracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.appxray.debug.disable=true at the end of the Eclipse Target in the shortcut used to launch Eclipse

If none of these work, don't shoot the messenger! This is just from my own research with this problem in Eclipse Neon.2.

Comment: Worked for me! (#2). Thank you! - Eclipse Photon

Comment: Disable AppXray worked for me. I did not try other two.