# STS SpringSourceToolsuite 3.8.2 JPA Event Handlers

Tags: windows, performance, jpa, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, eventhandler

I have a fresh installed STS 3.8.2 with one additional plugin subclipse and lombok. I did several fresh installs, but somehow that version has performance troubles. Versions till 3.8.1 worked fine. The most annoying is the JPA Event handler always blocking the Eclipse. I tried to turn off validations already, but it still comes. I am using Windows 10.

[image]

Any clue how I can avoid that?

Comment: would be interesting to see what is going on under the hood. Can you capture a thread dump while STS hangs in those operations (using jps and jstack)?

Comment: and maybe this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649847/eclipse-kepler-jpa-project-change-event-handler-waiting

Comment: Hey Martin, I opened an issue, first dump had been provided there : https://issuetracker.springsource.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/STS-4407