# Disable JPA Java Change Event Handler

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jboss-tools

I have been using Eclipse for many years (usually Jboss Developer Studio) and have been plagued by Eclipse often running, or waiting to run *JPA Java Change Event Handler*

[image: JPA Event Handler in Eclipse]

Currently I am working on a project that doesnt use JPA, yet these Event Handler still appears.

I have seen varies other SO and forum posts related to this, but I have not found a solution that works.

I have tried removing Dali and any plugins that show when searching for JPA - but the problem still remains.  For example, I have removed the following - but the problem remains:

[image: removed pluggins]

I am using Eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a Release

Answer (score 0):

Try this (It worked for me):

**Windows**:

```
cd eclipse_install_directory

mkdir disabled\features && mkdir disabled\plugins

move plugins\org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled\plugins
move features\org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled\features
```

**Linux**:

```
cd eclipse_install_directory

mkdir -p disabled/features && mkdir -p disabled/plugins

mv plugins/org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled/plugins
mv features/org.eclipse.jpt.* disabled/features
```

source: [http://w3cgeek.com](http://w3cgeek.com/eclipse-kepler-jpa-project-change-event-handler-waiting.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) Disable JPA validator + 2) Eclipse restart: works for me in Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014872/281411

Comment: This is not a solution, because I have completely disabled the Validation but this annoying "bug" is still present.